# How to determine the span for an eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Currently, I am trying to solve the following exercise.
However, it is not clear to me how we can determine the spans by the given matrices.

I have tried to determine the null space for each eigenspace before determining the span, but I'm not getting the same answer as described in the solutions.

My answers:

$$
E_1 (\alpha =0)=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\
E_2(\alpha = 1)= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\
E_1(\alpha=2)= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I've got the same eigenvalues and alpha values as in the solutions. I understand how I can compute this.

As you can see, I am not calculating the eigenspaces correctly, but I don't know where I made the mistakes.

Could someone explain to me how I can compute the eigenspaces from the matrices?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: By "derive the spans", do you mean "compute the eigenspaces"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, I do understand the principles of computing the eigenspaces, but somehow I am not able to get the same eigenspaces and their corresponding spans. Sorry for the weird phrasing of the question. Could you help me by either giving hints or an explanation for this exercise?

Comment: Could you edit your question to say what eigenspace you **do** get for at least one example where your answer disagrees with the answer provided?

Comment: @BenGrossmann If I am correct the changes should be visible right now. It is my first time using MathJax so sorry if it is a bit messy. 

The main thing that I don't understand is what the first step is. I tried (A-xI) where x is the eigenvalue and I the identity matrix, but I'm not sure whether I'm using the correct eigenvalue and what steps should be performed after this step.

Comment: For the first eigenspace, where does the vector $(1,1,0)$ come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on the case where $\alpha = 0$. We want to compute the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 1$. To do this, we calculate the nullspace of the matrix
$$
M = A - \lambda I = \pmatrix{1 & \alpha & 0\\ 0 & \alpha + 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 3 - \alpha} - \lambda \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
\\ =
\pmatrix{1 & (0) & 0\\ 0 & (0) + 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 3 - (0)} - (1)\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
\\ = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&2}.
$$
The nullspace of this matrix is the set of solutions to the equation
$$
Mx = 0 \implies \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&2}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = 0 \\
\implies \begin{cases}
0=0\\
x_3 = 0\\
2x_3 = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
There are a few ways to get a basis for the solution space, but I think that the most intuitive approach here is to note that $x$ will be a solution iff it is of the form $x = (x_1,x_2,0)$ (i.e. we only need to have $x_3=0$). We can express this as
$$
x = x_1\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} + x_2 \pmatrix{0\\1\\0}.
$$
Because the eigenspace $E_1(A)$ consists of all vectors of this form, we may state that
$$
E_1(A) = \operatorname{span}\left\{\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1\\0} \right\}.
$$

---

Regarding the last eigenspace: we note that for $\lambda = 1, \alpha = 2,$
$$
A - \lambda I = \pmatrix{0&2&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
The corresponding system of equations is
$$
2x_2 = 0, \quad 2x_2 + x_3 = 0. 
$$
By plugging the first equation into the second, we come to the conclusion that these equations imply that $x_2 = x_3 = 0$. Thus, every vector can be written in the form
$$
x = \pmatrix{x_1\\0\\0} = x_1  \pmatrix{1\\0\\0},
$$
which is to say that the eigenspace is the **span** of the vector $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. However, I still don't understand how it is possible that you have a different span than stated in the answers. I think that I got the second eigenspace correct right now, namely x = (1, 1, 0). But when I do exactly the same steps for the last eigenspace, I still get a different answer, namely x = (1, 0, 1). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mart The vectors I use are different, but the *actual span* of the vectors is the same, so my answer is the same as the answer given. Note in particular that, by definition, 
$$
\operatorname{span}\left\{ \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, \pmatrix{1\\1\\0}\right\} = \\
\left\{\alpha \pmatrix{1\\0\\0} + \beta \pmatrix{1\\1\\0} \mid \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R\right\} = \\
\left\{\pmatrix{\alpha + \beta \\ \beta \\ 0} \mid \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R\right\},
$$
which is the simply the set of all vectors whose third entry is zero.

Comment: @Mart Also you keep using language strangely. What you computed is the **second eigenvector**, not the second eigenspace.

Comment: Regarding the last eigenspace, see my latest edit.

Comment: Everything is clear to me right now. I misunderstood the principles of eigenspaces and eigenvectors and the definition of spanned vectors. Thank you very much!